# Snowflake: Number out of representable range: type FIXED[SB16](38,36){nullable}, value 772.401828000000000000000000

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We built a very complex SQL for calculation.

This SQL uses multiple subqueries and GROUP BY ROLLUP.

When this SQL was executed, Snowflake returned an error:

**Number out of representable range: type FIXED[SB16](38,36){nullable}, value 772.401828000000000000000000**

The data type of all the numeric fields we use is `NUMBER(18,6)`.

It seems that the Snowflake engine expands the data type to `NUMBER(38,36)` when calculating.

But I checked the documentation: [Snowflake Doc: Arithmetic Operators](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-arithmetic.html).

The doc said that the maximum scale is 12 digits.

I don't know why it is `NUMBER(38,36)`.

---

Our SQL is probably like this:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(Parent1)
 , MAX(Parent2)
 , MAX((Value1 * (1 - Value2) - Value3 + Value4 + Value5) / (Value1 * (1 - Value2)))
 , Parent1 || Parent2 AS ParentGroup
 , (Value1 * (1 - Value2) - Value3 + Value4 + Value5) / (Value1 * (1 - Value2)) AS ValueGroup
FROM TableName
INNER JOIN SomeTables ...
GROUP BY ROLLUP(4, 5)
;
```

---

This is a strange error. Why does the scale become 36?

Comment: It is a bug in Snowflake. Try to cast intermediate results: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Number-out-of-representable-range-error-occurs-during-the-multiplication-of-numeric-values

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this seems to be different from what I encountered. We are using ```NUMBER(18,6)```, and the calculated value is not large, it will not overflow.